# How to inject dependency into classes other than asmx web service code behind using Ninject in ASP.NET Web Application?

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a asp.net web application which has an asmx web service and then ClassA. I have been creating object of ClassA from code behind of asmx web service. My ClassA and asmx web service depends upon instance of ClassB which is declared in another project.

I have been using Ninject to inject dependency. I am successfully able to inject ClassB in code behind of asmx web service but not in ClassA.

How do we inject dependency into ClassA?

Please help.
thanks

Comment: When you say you can't do it for the ClassA dependency, what do you mean- error message? `null` object being injected? If your kernel can inject instances of `ClassB` into one class (the webservice class) then it should be able to inject into any other class as well.

Comment: @StephenByrne ASP.NET page inherit from Ninject.Web.PageBase, Master Page inherit from Ninject.Web.MasterPageBase, asmx web service inherit form Ninject.Web.WebServiceBase and so on. Because of this inheritence i guess Ninject is able to inject dependency into these classes. But classes other than these, ClassA in my case doesn't inherit from any classes from Ninject so Dependency Injection doesn't work for this case and i am looking to find out how to inject dependency into such classes.

Comment: Ah I see. Not so sure you can directly inject in this case *but* you could perhaps create a `StandardKernel` instance in for e.g global.asax, register bindings for `ClassB` on that kernel, and use this in `ClassA` instances to get your `ClassB` instances. Not ideal I know but it might work for you.